# Deploy C# application that uses third party COM (Activex) object causes application to crash

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, activex

I have developed an C#-WPF application that uses multiple third party dlls. Some of them which are written in C# works fine when the program is running in another PC, but one dll which is ActiveX Visual Basic 6.0 causes program to crash with the exception that class is not found. Well, I have installed that dll into the registry using regsvr32 (in system32 and in sysWOW64) and PC says that registration is done successfully, but still program crashes. I have tried also to "Embed" and not to "Embed" types of this dll (creating a local copy) and still program crashes. In one of this PC I have installed Visual Studio and run the program from visual studio removing and then adding the reference that causes program to crash. After that the program running from Visual Studio works fine, but again the compiled version from other PC crashes saying Class not found.

Important: When I'm testing program in other PC I'm copying Visual Studio project repo in usb and running the program from usb in other PC. Do not know if this may cause the problem

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the third party dll needed also that another program installed in machine, but this was not specified in documentation. After installing this program everything works fine